# TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float keeps persisting as an error in word cloud building program

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am trying to build a word cloud image by passing the program a .txt file then iterating through said txt file, processing out any punctuations and uninteresting filler words, then passing the processed dictionary to an external word cloud module.
I have already set the file_contents into a word list and split them. Then iterated through the list to replace any punctuations with empty strings and then set the dictionary to iterate through the list and store the words in said dictionary. Once the results are stored in the dictionary they're checked for a list of filler words and if there are matches they are replaced with an empty string, then the dict values are returned. I've tried everything and still can't find what's wrong on my own.

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
# Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
"we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
"their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
"have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
"all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

# LEARNER CODE START HERE
words = [file_contents.split()]
frequencies = {}
for word in words:
    if punctuations in words:
        words.replace(punctuations, "")
        frequencies = {word +1} 
        if uninteresting_words in frequencies:
            frequencies.replace(uninteresting_words, "")
        return frequencies
    return words

#wordcloud
cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)
return cloud.to_array()
```

Any tips and pointers will help, thanks

Comment: What's an example of what you would expect as `file_contents`?

Comment: just a file containing "example" text, basically if you just took a paragraph or chunk of a book, article, etc. and pasted it in a text file

Answer (score 0):

I created an example... by no means is it a *perfect* one, but I think it achieves what you're asking. I provided comments as explanation

```py
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    # words = file_contents.split()
    # split the file contents and convert all the words into lower case
    words = [x.lower() for x in file_contents.split()]
    # init a 'frequencies' dictionary
    frequencies = {}
    # loop through each word in the 'words' list
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        # we only care when the word isn't in the uninteresting_words list
        if word not in uninteresting_words:
            # loop through each punctuation
            for punc in punctuations:
                # replacing the punctuation with ''
                words[i] = words[i].replace(punc, '')
            # add the word to 'frequencies'/increase the value stored
            if words[i] in frequencies:
                frequencies[words[i]] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[words[i]] = 1
    return frequencies

print(calculate_frequencies("I am repeating repeating repeating."))
```